# How to set database options using SQL Server SMO and powershell from a hash?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, smo

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Powershell 2.0

I have created a hash of options that I want to set in a SQL Server database like so:

```
$dbopts = @{
    "AutoCreateStatistics"=$true;
    "AutoUpdateStatistics"=$true;
    "AutoShrink"=$false;
    };
```

I want to set these options on a SQL Server database using SMO. I created a function which accepts a SMO Database object and the DatabaseOptions hash as inputs.

```
function setDatabaseOptions {
    param ($db, $opts);

    foreach ($opt in $db.DatabaseOptions) {
        # what to write here?

    }

}
```

I want to set the options in the hash to the database. Not sure the best way to do this. Any suggestions? An example, to set an option explicitly you would do

`$db.DatabaseOptions.AutoCreateStatistics = $true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no disrespect to Shay as in his last comment try  to enumerate the hashtable.

```
function setDatabaseOptions {      
param ($db, $opts)          
   foreach ($key in $opts.Keys) { $db.DatabaseOptions.$key = $opts[$key] }
   $db.DatabaseOptions.Alter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign the correct hash item to the property of the database. I don't work with SMO but you may also need to invoke a method to apply the updates.

```
function setDatabaseOptions {

    param ($db, $opts)

        $opt = $db.DatabaseOptions

        $opt.AutoCreateStatistics = $opts['AutoCreateStatistics']
        $opt.AutoUpdateStatistics = $opts['AutoUpdateStatistics']
        $opt.AutoShrink= $opts['AutoShrink']    
}
```

Comment: I don't want the options hardcoded in the function but read from the hash. ie. `$opt.[$myHashItem] = $opts.['$myHashItemValue']` I hope that's clear enough to understand!

Comment: I'm not following you, "$opt.[$myHashItem] = $opts.['$myHashItemValue']" is not hard coded?

Comment: `$opt.AutoCreateStatistics` is a hard coded database option. I want to iterate through the $opts hash and set each option to each value, but not explicitly declare it. IOW I will need a foreach loop to go through each one. The $opts hash may vary each time it is called, hence the reason I can't have them hard-coded. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: hashtables gives you direct access to its members by specifying the item name. I fins it awkward, and inefficient, to enumerate it just to find the member you need. If you still want to do that this way consider replacing the hashtable with an collection of psobjects.